# How can I load a numpy byte array that is stored in an S3 without writing it to disk?

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3

I have a numpy array in an S3 that i want to load into my python script. The array was uploaded in the following way with boto3:

```
s3.put_object(
     Body=np.array(array).tobytes(),
     Bucket='bucketname',
     Key='filename'
)
```

I know that it is an array with shape (1, 356), and has dtype=float.

How can I get this item from S3 into my python script without downloading the file manually then loading it into numpy?

Even if I download the file manually, how would i go about loading it into numpy?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting it working like so:

```
obj = s3.Bucket('bucketname').Object('key')
obj = obj.get()['Body']

f = np.frombuffer(obj.read())
```

where s3 is a boto3.resource('s3') object